# Wicket interaction between wicket-applications on localhost

Tags: java, ajax, session, wicket, tabbed-browsing

I'm experiencing abnormal behaviour in ajax-related clicks in two Wicket Applications that both run on the same `localhost` on different ports (both served by `Jetty`)

I have two applications open in two tabs in Chrome. When I click on an `AjaxLink` in one of the applications, it sometimes works and sometimes does nothing (or something in the other Wicket tabs, as I see the tab title doing something).

This leads to undesired behaviour, as the links no longer work as required.

What can I do to prevent this interaction between tabs?

Comment: This is not behavior provided by Wicket. If it happens then it is a bug either in Wicket or in your application(s).

Comment: I find it hard to blame Wicket here as this happens across different applications running on completely isolated server instances. Does this happen in all browsers, or just Chrome like in your previous similar problem with AjaxLink? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508123/wicket-multi-tab-ajax-page-serialization

Comment: It might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619388/why-does-running-multiple-wicket-applications-cause-ajax-conflicts

Comment: @Gimby yes that seems related (even duplicate?)

Comment: Possibly you can try it out by making one server listen on your internal (network) IP address rather than localhost, then access that application through the IP address in your browser.

Comment: @robau if that solves it or is a valid workaround, consider creating a self-answer.

Comment: @robau you're not going to get any with what little you've presented, and it is perfectly valid for a question to have multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

I now use this:

`this.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().setName( applicationCookieName )`

And change the `applicationCookieName` per application, that seems to prevent it.

It is probably caused by the JSESSIONID being shared by default, as can written in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646933/461499